# TSQL Operators IN vs INNER JOIN

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2014:

Is there any performance difference between the following statements?

```
DELETE FROM MyTable where PKID IN (SELECT PKID FROM @TmpTableVar)
```

AND

```
DELETE FROM MyTable INNER JOIN @TmpTableVar t ON MyTable.PKID = t.PKID
```

Comment: Take a look at the execution plans for each. In this case they are likely going to be identical.

Comment: The  execution plans are based on current statistics. They might be identical today but change later. That is why I am looking for broader rules.

Comment: I did some tests ,both are similar almost in all cases http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38444729/most-efficient-way-to-select-rows-where-the-id-exists-in-a-second-table/38445287#38445287

Comment: To clarify: the `EXPLAIN` verb is used to obtain execution-plan information.

Comment: But even with different statistics, the statistics would be the same at run time. Not sure what you mean by broader rules??

Comment: @AllanXu the execution plans *are* the rules. The query will execute using them based mainly on the *indexes* defined on MyTable, then the statistics of that table. Table variables have no indexes or statistics, so size changes won't affect how the query is executed. If you used an in-memory table in 2016 though, things would be very different

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know the execution plans are the rules. My point is that the execution plans can change with circumstances around the database and the table. So I was hoping not jumping into conclusion with creating a test table and compare the execution plans.

Comment: So, is it safe o assume the two queries identical?

Comment: Check out this article that goes pretty deep on this topic. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/08/17/exists-vs-in/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your given example the execution plans will be the same (most probably).

But having same execution plans doesn't mean that they are the best execution plans you can possibly have for this statement.

The problem I see in both of your queries is the use of the `Table Variable`.

SQL Server always assumes that there is only 1 row in the table variable. Only in SQL Server 2014 and later version this assumption has been changed to 100 rows.

So no matter how many rows you have this the table variable SQL Server will always assume you have one row in the `@TmpTableVar`.

You can change your code slightly to give SQL Server a better idea of how many rows there will be in that table by replacing it with a `Temporary table` and since it is a `PK_ID` Column in your table variable you can also create an index on that table, to give best chance to sql server to come up with the best possible execution plan for this query.

```
SELECT PKID INTO #Temp
FROM @TmpTableVar

-- Create some index on the temp table here .....

DELETE FROM MyTable
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM #Temp t
              WHERE MyTable.PKID = t.PKID)
```

**Note**

In operator will work fine since it is a primary key column in the table variable. but if you ever use IN operator on a nullable column, the results may surprise you, The IN operator goes all pear shape as soon as it finds a NULL values in the column it is checking on.

I personally prefer Exists operator for such queries but inner joins should also work just fine but avoid IN operators if you can.

Comment: Thank you for help. Is the number of rows concern around @tableVariables applies to inner join approach as well? I am thinking to consider inner join as the safer approach going forward.

Comment: Not a problem, and yes it can cause sql server to come up with a less efficient execution plan, because sql server assumes there is only one row in that table a join on the Primary key column should bring back only one row. But this could not be the case, hence avoid using table variables in such scenarios.